# Is this the right approach to add an element to an array?

Tags: c, for-loop, random

I have an array.

```
int Game[100];
```

I want to make a random sequence of two numbers inside this array. ( 0 and 1 ).

```
int i;
int Game[];
for(i = 100; i >= pos; i--) {
       // Random number ( 0 or 1 )
       int v = (int)rand() / (int)RAND_MAX;
       Game[i] = Game[i-1];
       Game[i] = v;
}
```

Is this the right approach?

Comment: If Game is of size 100. Game[i] with `i == 100` (first iteration of the loop) will be out of the array.

Comment: Why `Game[i] = Game[i-1]`? You are eventually overwriting `Game[i]` in next line. Also, `i` should start from 99 as `Game[100]` does not refer to valid location

Comment: What is `pos` value?

Comment: `int Game[];` ?

Comment: regarding: `int v = (int)rand() / (int)RAND_MAX;`  This is unlikely to produce what you want.  Suggest:  `int v = rand() % 2;`  as each execution of this statement will result in either `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to fill the Game array with a succession of random 0 and 1 values you can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> /* include this if you want to create new sequences at each run */

int main()
{
    
    int Game[100];

    /* create a new seed based on current time to have different sequences at each run */  
    srand( (unsigned int)time( NULL );

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(Game)/sizeof(Game[0]);i++) {
       
       // Random number ( 0 or 1 )
       Game[i] = rand() % 2;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(Game)/sizeof(Game[0]);i++) {
        printf ("%d\n",Game[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: remember the need to set a unique 'seed' value, other wise the same values will be produced each execution.  Suggest insert `#include <time.h>`  and early in `main()` insert: `srand( (unsigned int)time( NULL );`